# Change document background image in javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the html documents background image in a javascript function but I'm having some difficulty with it. This is what I have:

```
function changeBgImage(){

    document.background = "url('images/SecondBackground.png')";

}
```

But as I said, not working.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/SecondBackground.png')";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeBGImage() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://images.cheezburger.com/completestore/2010/7/9/fe8e91c5-c3f1-40cf-a034-983e8683ba73.jpg)";
};
```

That'll do it!

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but you need .body as well.

```
document.body.style.background = "url('images/SecondBackground.png')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
              document.getElementById("id of body").setAttribute("style","background-url:'images/SecondBackground.png'")
```